# Why does pylab always plot to the last created figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to create 2 figures at the same time.  I thought I could plot into each figure by specifying the desired axis as shown in the code below, but all of the data goes into the last created figure (here, `fig2`).

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

fig1 = pl.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
gs1 = pl.GridSpec(4, 4)

fig2 = pl.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
gs2 = pl.GridSpec(4, 4)

for axis_counter in range(11):
    ax = pl.subplot(gs1[axis_counter])
    ax.plot([0, 10], [0, 10])
```

When I run this nothing plots in the `fig1` axes, it all goes into the `fig2` axes even though I'm explicitly calling `gs1` here.  I imagine pylab is latching onto the last created figure, but that behavior does not make sense.

Comment: The pylab interface is terrible for things like this. Everything goes into `fig2` because that's what would be returned by `plt.gcf`. Use the object-oriented interface instead to explicitly associate gridspecs and axes with figures.

Comment: ["Since heavily importing into the global namespace may result in unexpected behavior, the use of pylab is strongly discouraged."](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to never use pylab.

If your in an interactive console session, `pyplot` is ok. But really, you should use the object-oriented interface. That means:

- importing pyplot
- create a figure either directly or with axes via (`pyplot.subplots`)
- operate on those figures and axes directly.

In your case, this means:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot

fig1 = pyplot.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
gs1 = fig1.add_gridspec(4, 4)

fig2 = pyplot.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
gs2 = fig2.add_gridspec(3, 3)

for axis_counter in range(11):
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(gs1[axis_counter])
    ax.plot([0, 10], [0, 10])


ax = fig2.add_subplot(gs2[3])
ax.plot([0, 10], [0, 10])
```